# Callback function is executed right away

Tags: javascript

I have a confirm popup that ask for yes or no, this is the code:

```
Confirm({
    Title: 'Warning',
    Message: 'Are you sure?',
    Buttons: [{
        text: 'Yes',
        callback: function(){
            RRSubmitRemoveReportRequest($(this));
        },
        highlighted: true
    }, {
        text: 'No)',
        callback: null,
        type: 'no'
    }]
});
```

If if send the parameter $(this), I should use an anonymous function, otherwise it calls the function right away, anybody can explain me this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `callback` property needs to be set to a `function`.

If you do:

```
callback: RRSubmitRemoveReportRequest($(this))
```

you are setting `callback` to the *return value* of the `RRSubmitRemoveReportRequest` function.

You need to pass it a function.  `RRSubmitRemoveReportRequest` is a function, `RRSubmitRemoveReportRequest($(this))` is a function call, so it's ran and its return value is used.

When you do:

```
callback: function(){
    RRSubmitRemoveReportRequest($(this));
}
```

you are passing a function, that when called, will call `RRSubmitRemoveReportRequest` correctly.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to understand with an example:

```
function foo(i){
    return i*10;
}

var x = foo(1); // execute foo with 1 parameter;
```

---

```
var x = function(){ // creates a callback to the foo function.
    foo(1);
};
```

---

```
var x = foo; // pointer to foo function and then:
x(1);
```

---

Bottom line, a callback should be a **function** that will be invoked somewhere in the future, not a value of a function.